# Excel algorithm to execute funcion in the right order

Tags: excel, algorithm

My add-in has a set of UDF which has to connect to a serve to return a result. 
Unfortunately for each function call is necessary to establish a connection that makes the process time consuming. I wish I could establish a single connection to retrieve all data at once.

```
Cells A1:
myUdf1("argument1",myUdf2("HelloWorld!"),"argument3")
Cells A2:
myUdf3= (A1)
Cells A3:
myUdf4= (workday(today(),2),"argument2")
```

As you may have noticed the order of execution is critical to get the function results. The information should be sent to the server in the right order. For instance in the above scenario it would be necessary to first calculate the result for myUdf2 then calculate myUdf1 and finally calculate myUdf3. For the cell A3 first it is necessary to return result for excel custom functions and then for the myUdf4.

As business grad I have no idea how to tackle this problem. So I ask for some ideas.

Comment: To get a prompt, informed response, It may help if you actually showed the code that is being executed. It is very likely the code could be improved.

Comment: Do all of the code in a single UDF and return an array result.  If the output should not be a box, then use cell references to put things where you actually want.